# AWS DMS Migration challenges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-migration, aws-dms

In a migration scenario from OnPrem SQL to AWS SQL type databases, Thinking through cases where `AWS DMS` might pose additional challenges and perhaps should be avoided for the sake of simplicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the DMS Considerations are listed below:

- How large are our databases?
- How many tables do we have in each database?
- Do we have primary keys on all the existing tables? (This is highly recommended for DMS)
- Do we have any identity columns?
- Do we use truncate tables? How frequently?
- Do we have temporal tables?
- Do we have any column level encryption today?
- How often are DDL's executed?
- `SELECT * INTO new_table FROM existing_table` is not supported. Do we do that frequently?